# Documentation: Lost Changes and "Already Reviewed"

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-proposals

I recently typed up a significant amount for the [Introduction to Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/elasticsearch/941/introduction-to-elasticsearch) documentation, but a bunch of micro-edits got merged ahead of it. I was keeping track of them and updating my example to include them, but after a few of them I was no longer able to get to my changes:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/46642

- I did have this open in a tab, but I made the mistake of trying to open a section in a new tab by center-clicking the pencil. This changed the *current* page, then redirected in the same tab and notified me that my changes had already been reviewed.

becomes

https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/proposed/changes/46642

Hopefully those changes will return to the living soon.

It's a beta, so I'm not terribly concerned about the issue, but I think this presents an interesting problem with the editing process, which likely led to this bug:

- Micro-edits tend to get accepted more easily because they only require a single reviewer, which forces bigger edits to be fixed and go through the exact same process endlessly.

  - I assume that, as the service gets more use that major updates will be less common, but it's currently being gamed by generally less knowledgeable users with micro-edits.
  - Large updates, while obviously discouraged in the long run, become nearly impossible to make for active sections.
  - Slow reviews or practically no reviews as the case has been in my case seem to be making it even harder.